# $b_n \rightharpoonup b$ in $L^q(Q) \forall q < \infty$, $b_n \to b$ in $C^0([0,T];H^{-1})$ implies $b_n(t) \rightharpoonup b(t)$ in $L^q(\Omega)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

This question stems from the proof of Theorem A.1 on page 425 of [this paper](http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~porretta/papers/Blanchard-Porretta-JDE.pdf).

> Let $Q=(0,T)\times \Omega$. Suppose $b_n \rightharpoonup b$ in $L^q(Q)$ for any $q < \infty$ and $b_n \to b$ in $C^0([0,T];H^{-1}(\Omega))$. This strong convergence yields that $b_n(t) \rightharpoonup b(t)$ in $L^q(\Omega)$ for any $q < \infty$.

I don't understand how this conclusion holds. Does anyone know?

Coincidentally [a similar question was asked on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/845903/if-u-n-to-u-in-c0-th-1-and-lvert-u-n-rvert-l-infty-leq-c-the), for which I placed a bounty but received no answers so I think it is OK to post here as I have had no luck.

Comment: perhaps you should tell us what is the connection between $u_n$ and $b_n$?

Comment: Sorry I meant $b_n$, not $u_n$. Typo.

Comment: I think you are omitting an important hypothesis (mentioned in the paper), namely that the $b_n(t)$ are uniformly bounded in $L^q(\Omega)$.  With this uniform bound, one can obtain weak convergence through testing against $C^\infty_c(\Omega)$ functions, at which point one can use the $C^0$ strong convergence to conclude.

Comment: Thanks @TerryTao but I don't see any mention in the paper about $b_n(t)$ being uniformly bounded in $L^q(\Omega)$. The only pointwise claim I see is (A.7) which is what we want to show. Sorry if I miss something obvious.

Comment: It looks like the $b_n$ are in fact bounded in $L^\infty$, because the $u_n$ are.  In any case, from the uniform boundedness principle, the $b_n(t)$ _have_ to be bounded in $L^q$ if one is to have weak convergence, so such a bound must already appear somewhere in the argument.